# Not found error on azure container with mounted volume

Tags: azure, docker

I have deployed a docker container on Azure with the following CLI:

```
/home/luis/bin/az container create \
    --resource-group mlcontainers2 \
    --name modeldiagnosticsvolume \
    --image mlcontainers2.azurecr.io/samples/modeldiagnostics \
    --registry-login-server mlcontainers2.azurecr.io \
    --registry-password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   \
    --registry-username mlcontainers2 \
    --ports 80 5000 5100 \
    --ip-address public \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name cs217dfd5a81083x41faxb08 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name mlstorage \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/data_automl
```

The container is running but when I make an API call I don't get response.

After running:

```
az container logs --name automl \
                     --resource-group mlcontainers2
```

This is shown in the logs:

```
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2019-09-18 08:10:22 wk-caas-a254ed947c89463fb2838437151e02a3-e0eb3a654e2770b95a94bb werkzeug[8] INFO  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-09-18 08:11:15 wk-caas-a254ed947c89463fb2838437151e02a3-e0eb3a654e2770b95a94bb werkzeug[8] INFO 10.240.255.55 - - [18/Sep/2019 08:11:15] "POST /api/AutoML HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This last line:

```
werkzeug[8] INFO 10.240.255.55 - - [18/Sep/2019 08:11:15] "POST /api/AutoML HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Is what I get in response after making the API call.

EDIT:

On the container I'm running a Flask app to access my model through an API:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://52.241.XXX.XXX:5000/api/AutoML"
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
```

**edit2** 
I tried changing 5100 to 5000 in the docker file, I get his error from the API call:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='52.241.132.234', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/AutoML (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb8ba726320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')
```

**EDIT 3**

I tried with a container without the mounted volume I'm getting the exact same error:

```
2019-09-18 18:07:11 wk-caas-4301d2868e144ac59af68a0ad87e4442-726fc0246008fe50938461 werkzeug[8] INFO 10.240.255.55 - - [18/Sep/2019 18:07:11] "POST /api/AutoML HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Hence, I think the error is that the volume is not been mounted properly.

**EDIT 4:**

The images work well locally and are called the same way from the API, except that I use localhost instead of the IP of the instance. I have tested with ports 5000 and 5100 depending on which is available. By default, I use port 5000 since is the default port for flask as well.

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/AutoML"
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
```

Comment: What do you mean the API call?

Comment: @CharlesXu a flask API on the contaiener. I just updated the question.

Comment: Which ports do you expose inside the image for the API server?

Comment: EXPOSE 5100 on docker file

Comment: @CharlesXu traying with 5000

Comment: @CharlesXu Didn't worked

Comment: If other ports useful expect the port 5000?

Comment: did not undestood that.

Comment: I see you expose ports 80, 5000 and 5100 in the commands, so all the ports necessary?

Comment: @CharlesXu I want to be able to use either port 5000 or 5100. 80 I don't need it, can that be the reason?

Comment: @CharlesXu I tried with the same image without mounting the volume. I got the same error, I edited the question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To create the Azure Container Instance with the custom image, first, you need to make sure the image can work well locally. When the image is OK, then you can create the ACI with the image and expose the right port.

**Update:**

In this issue, the problem is that the mount path in the command should be `/app/data_automl/`.

Comment: The images work well locally, but I need them running on Azure.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Which port do you expose in the image and how do you access the API server?

Comment: Other images are working fine on azure too, the issue is with the ones than need a volume to read/store data

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez I see you said it also give the same error if you do not use the persistent volume? So try to just expose the port that you use in the image in the command. I think it's the port caused the error if the image is OK.

Comment: I just added details on how I call it locally at the end of the question. Yes, it is giving the same error, but the app reads that unit when is called, hence it makes sense to get an error, my point was that since the error is the same I think that when I mount the volume the container does not have access to it, atleast not now.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez If the image is Linux based, then the persistent volumes in the file share is no problem when you use the account name and account key. The key has all permissions as the admin user.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez If you do not mind, you can provide me the image and the Dockerfile, I could test it for you.

Comment: Sure, where should I share it? dockerhub?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199662/discussion-between-luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez-and-charles-xu).

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Well, if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez What about this issue? Do you solve the problem? Does the answer works for you?

Comment: i solved it, but was another issue. paths have to be like: /app/data instead /app/data/

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Ohh, we both go in the wrong way. You can add an answer to show the solution.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Or I add the solution in the answer for you, can you accept it?